# jqplot donut data disappearing

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am using jqplot for a donut graph display, however I am coming across an unusual issue.

The data sets are missing in the browser.

the lines that should read:

```
var s1 = [['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]];
var s2 = [['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6], ['d', 9]];

var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart3', [s1, s2], {
seriesDefaults: {
  // make this a donut chart.
  renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
  rendererOptions:{
    // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
    sliceMargin: 3,
    // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
    startAngle: -90,
    showDataLabels: true,
    // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
    // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
    dataLabels: 'value'
  }
}
});
```

have the data missing in the browser, so only show:

```
 var s1 = ;
 var s2 = ;
```

This leaves me with a blank page as there is no data to form the graph. 
The issue seems to be with double brackets. If I remove the container brackets for the data then it is seen by the browser, but then the code doesn't work as it can't understand it.

```
var s1 = ['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20];
var s2 = ['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6], ['d', 9];
```

I've not come across something like this before where what I code isn't even seen by the browser. I can't see I am doing anything differently from any other examples on the net.

This is the full code I'm using;

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/js/jquery.jqplot.css">


</head>
<body style="background-color: #000;">
<div id="chart3" style="height:300px; width:500px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var s1 = [['a',6], ['b',8], ['c',14], ['d',20]];
var s2 = [['a', 8], ['b', 12], ['c', 6], ['d', 9]];

var plot3 = $.jqplot('chart', [s1], {
seriesDefaults: {
  // make this a donut chart.
  renderer:$.jqplot.DonutRenderer,
  rendererOptions:{
    // Donut's can be cut into slices like pies.
    sliceMargin: 3,
    // Pies and donuts can start at any arbitrary angle.
    startAngle: -90,
    showDataLabels: true,
    // By default, data labels show the percentage of the donut/pie.
    // You can show the data 'value' or data 'label' instead.
    dataLabels: 'value'
  }
}
});
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqplot.pieRenderer.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqplot.donutRenderer.js"></script>
</body>
```

As you can see there isn't a lot to get wrong here. I've tried different versions of jquery as was an issue in some cases. I've tried putting the scripts in different places on the page but hasn't helped.

This is a link to a similar working example I've used as a basis and I can't see why mine is not working.

http://jsfiddle.net/devmgs/1xcn4bf5/1/

many thanks for any help

Richard

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like all that is required is to put a space between the outer bracket and the inner content. The data is then displayed.

Had another error but moving the script links from the bottom of the page to the header solved that also. Should now work fine.